What's the problem with my tf.keras.input() function
when trying to train my model i am getting error - "ValueError: Cannot convert '8' to a shape", when the shape of my X_train is (5347,28).
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1])))
model.add(Dense(units=25,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=15 , activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1 , activation='linear'))

model.summary()

loss_fun = tf.keras.losses.MSE
model.compile(loss = loss_fun,
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=25)

I tried differnet things but still still goes some different error.

Can you please tell me whether your training dataset is properly converted into a tensor or numpy array? Without seeing the X_train and y_train data with the their dtypes, it's kind of hard to tell.

HI @Aniket Tiwari, The error you are facing The ValueError: Cannot convert '8' to a shape suggests an issue with the data shape or its input into the model. Verify that X_train and y_train have the correct dimensions:X_train should be a 2D array with shape (num_samples, num_features), where num_features should be 28 in your case.

y_train should be a 1D array with shape (num_samples,) for single output tasks. For regression with a single output, it can also be (num_samples, 1). If y_train is a 1D array and has the correct sample count, it should be fine. If it’s a 2D array, ensure it has the shape (num_samples, 1) for regression tasks.
